# Change a system setting missing from the UI directly?

Tags: settings, lenovo

I have a Lenovo S939 (Android 4.2.2, rooted) and the setting to change the default notification sound is missing. Is there a good app that can be used to browse all system settings and make changes directly (something like regedit in Windows). Or can this setting be changed in the file system by editing a XML file? If so, how can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer on XDA, tried it, worked: http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/change-setting-missing-ui-directly-t2927313

Basically they suggested to change the setting in build.props but the phone didnt pick that up. So in the end I overwrote the default audio file with the one I wanted.

Comment: Please provide some relevant context here, so that if the link ever becomes unavailable this answer will still contain enough information to be useful.